# Generating random object paths then recording the data

Tags: modeling, animation

So I am quite new to blender so please go easy on me :)

I am creating a Variational Autoencoder for predicting an objects movement and I would like to use blender to illustrate the final path predition. (its for brain shift during surgery)

Issue 1:
I would like to create a path for an object x,y,z to travel to another point over a period of time. However, I would like to add some uncertainty to the path traveled and the time it takes so that the data is not the same each run. It will be a brain shape that will have 3-5 points that will determine the movement of the brain over time.

Issue 2:
I would then like to take, for example, 100 runs of the different paths and store this data to train and test the machine learning model. Then eventually run the model with blender to show how the brain will move.

Any advice is welcome! I really like blender and I think it could work but if im using the wrong software for the job let me know too! :)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: By uncertainty do you mean speeding up/slowing down, wiggling side to side, etc?

Comment: sorry for any confusion, let me clarify.

by uncertainty I mean the initial position is fixed but the final position is within a range of values and the time taken to travel to the final position may vary within a range too.

for example starting point is 0,0,0 but the ending range is a small-ish area around 1,1,1 +/- 0.001 in all axis. and the time will range from say 1second to 1.5seconds

thanks for the reply

Comment: I am kinda hoping to create a loop of say 1000 repitions of this "random" path (that is within the limits) to then create a dataset saved as a file which will be used to train/test the machine learning model i am working on. Then from that model to hopefully produce seperate data that will produce a similar animation that is within the same ranges. I hope this helps clarify :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is not clear exactly what you are asking at the moment, your post doesn't include any question and also seems to include several topics at the same time which goes against the rules of the site. Could you narrow it down to a specific issue you are encountering rather than a broad topic. Be sure to include a phrase with a question mark stating clearly what your question is

Comment: Blender isn't made for recording data, but you could definitely achieve this using the Python script editor in Blender.